# Emotion 11 get access to theme object with typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

Currently I have the following structure:

`src/styles/theme.ts`

```
const theme = {
  fonts: {
    body: 'Lato, sans-serif',
  },
  colors: {
    primary: '#3D63AE',
  },
};

// export type ThemeProps = {
//   theme: Theme;
// };

export default theme;
```

In `src/types/emotion.d.ts`:

```
import '@emotion/react';

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme {
    colors: {
      primary: string;
    };
    fonts: {
      body: string;
    };
  }
}
```

To type my `theme` I can do:

```
import { Theme } from '@emotion/react';

const theme: Theme = {
 // ...
```

**1)** Is this the preferred and cleanest way?

Also in e.g. my Header component styles file `src/components/Header/Header.styles.ts` I want to get access to my `theme` object.

I see people doing:

```
export type ThemeProps = {
 theme: Theme;
};
```

So in `Header.styles.ts` I can do:

`import { ThemeProps } from ???;`

```
export default ({ theme }: ThemeProps) => ({
  root: css`
    margin-top: ${theme.spaces.large};
  `,
```

**2)** But where do I have to declare this type?

And is above setup the recommended way?

**Update:**

I created a global declaration file `src/types/global.d.ts`, and added:

```
import { Theme } from '@emotion/react';

declare global {
  interface ThemeProps {
    theme: Theme;
  }
}
```

Now in `Header.styles.ts` I am able to use:

```
export default ({ theme }: ThemeProps) => ({
  root: css`
    margin-top: ${theme.spaces.large};
  `,
```

Comment: Both practice looks alright. Extending the builtin `Theme` interface from emotion is what their recommend I believe. As of `ThemeProps` I personally would put this kind of interface in the global namespace for convenience. `declare global { interface ThemeProps {} }`. Or if you prefer to import it from somewhere, you better have its path aliased, so you don’t have to use "../" everywhere.

Comment: @hackape sorry what do you mean with `I personally would put this kind of interface in the global namespace for convenience`? If I want to import it from somewhere from what filename (e.g. `types/styles.ts`?) should make sense?

Comment: `types/styles.ts` Yeah sure, that's just a matter of style. Name it whatever you like.

Comment: I'm just saying, if you do put `ThemeProps` in `src/types/styles.ts`, it's a good idea to also alias it in `tsconfig.json` like `compilerOptions.paths.myStyle: "src/types/styles.ts"`, then in your code, you can `import { ThemeProps } from "myStyle"` instead of `import { ThemeProps } from "../../types/styles.ts"`

Comment: And I'm sharing my personal practice. I would simply declare in my `src/index.ts` the following: `declare global { interface ThemeProps { theme: Theme } }`. Now anywhere in my code, I can just reference `ThemeProps` directly, without needing to `import` it.